# How to create responsive three column layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The left and right circle is fixed at `60px` width, the middle one needs to take the width that left.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to use css like `width: calc(100% - 100px);`

Comment: One of the main reasons I spend time here answering Qs is that I learn stuff. Like this! I didn't know about this, but it will be so useful. I did a fiddle to convince myself it works - http://jsfiddle.net/93oz9haz/

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `table`, it simply works across nearly all browsers.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}
.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table .middle {
    width: 100%;
}
.table .left span, .table .right span {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.table .middle span {
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="left"><span></span></div>
    <div class="middle"><span>Hello World</span></div>
    <div class="right"><span></span></div>
</div>
```